# Map QWidget to variable

Tags: c++, qt, templates, widget, mapper

The idea was to connect QWidget with a variable so that when text changes on a widget it will be also changed in a variable.

And do this with just one line like this

```
WidgetMapper::connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), someClass.var);
```

which would connect for example `QLineEdit` with a variable.

1) This would display `var` in a lineEdit

2) when lineEdit fires an `textChanged(QString)` signal - WidgetMapper would convert this QString to correct mapped type with stringstream and write it to `var`.

But i dont really know templates that well, and dont know if it is possible at all.
I dont think it is possible to use one WidgetMapper for every type, so i also tried creating separate instances for each type (`WidgetMapper<int> mapper;`) which would still be betten then writing setters and onTextChangedSlots for each QLiteEdit but i could not figure out how to make it work as well (converter part still could not figure out the correct type).

WidgetMapper is using QSignalMapper to map signal to QWidget, and it worked fine, the part i have troubles with - is converting QString to template variable.

So is it possible? And if yes how could i do this? Or maybe there already a solution for this problem? (Somehow use `QDataWidgetMapper` with a class that contains variables maybe?)

Comment: Why don't you use `QLineEdit::value()` and convert the returned value when you need it ?

Comment: @RomhaKorev because there are a lot of them and changes should change values in variables right after it was edited. So i would like avoiding writing onTextChanged slot for every QLineEdit to convert its text() to variable

Answer (score 2):

First of, connecting the variable would do nothing else than calling some function if it were possigle.

Second try using `QSignalMapper`, this way you could use a single slot for all widgets, given you  keep their pointers in an array with the index being the signal(int) emitted by the SignalMapper. This way your slot can just use `MyWidgetArray[i]->text()`.

Comment: but how do i then remember which Widget is for which variable?

Comment: take a look at QSignalMapper. You can emit int-signals for different widgets. Just create two arrays having the widgets and variables, then just use: ``MyVarArray[i] = MyWidgetArray.at[i]->text();`` where i is just the int emitted by QSignalMapper (this is my preferred way of managing lots of wigets of the same type in one slot)